# Extract Value From Dynamic JSON payload

Tags: mule, session-variables, mule-component, dataweave, anypoint-studio

I am running Mule 3 and is on dataweave 1.0
I have a JSON payload (with dynamic key and value) which occurs inside a For Each loop. Sample data is given below:

```
{
  "094d29c7-6abf-4acb-8513-e1d2d2b8998a": "900145600114256"
}
```

The key is UUID and value is an Identifier. I need to store the value in a sessionVar. Can someone help me with the dataweave 1.0 to extract the JSON value (900145600114256) from above? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use the pluck operator. This will go through each key value pair. In this case you would get the list of values

```
(payload pluck ((value,key) -> value))[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you do mot know what keys could be in your object.
[mapObject](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dw-core-functions-mapobject) function helps with this issue

```
%dw 2.0
var x={
  "094d29c7-6abf-4acb-8513-e1d2d2b8998a": "900145600114256"
}
output application/json
---
x mapObject ((value, key, index) ->
    {keyFromPaylod:key, valueFromPayload: value}
)
```

[image: Preview]

See how to work with unknown keys here https://simpleflatservice.com/mule4/WorkingWithUnknownKeys.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try this out.